# File uploader script not working properly

Tags: php, database, file-upload

I am trying to create a file upload script with PHP and MySql. But this sript is showing me the err.php page (which should get executed when there is any input validation error).I've tried tweaking it but no chance. following is my php script

```
    <?php

    //Start session

    session_start();



    //Include database connection details

    require_once('default.php');



    //Connect to mysql server

    $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PSWD);

    if(!$link) {

        die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());

    }



    //Select database

    $db = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME);

    if(!$db) {

        die("Unable to select database");

    }



    function clean($str) {

        $str = @trim($str);

        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {

            $str = stripslashes($str);

        }

        return mysql_real_escape_string($str);

    }





    //Function to sanitize values received from the form. Prevents SQL injection



    $name = clean($_POST['Name']);

    $toupld = ($_POST['file']);

    $source = clean($_POST['type']);

    $Desc = clean($_POST['Desc']);

    $By = clean($_POST['By']);

    $For = clean($_POST['For']);





    if($name == '') {

        $errmsg_arr[] = 'Name missing';

        $errflag = true;

    }

    if($toupld == '') {

        $errmsg_arr[] = 'Path missing';

        $errflag = true;

    }

    if($source == '') {

        $errmsg_arr[] = 'Type missing';

        $errflag = true;

    }



    if($Desc == '') {

        $errmsg_arr[] = 'Description missing';

        $errflag = true;

    }

    if($By == '') {

        $errmsg_arr[] = 'By missing';

        $errflag = true;

    }

    if($For == '') {

        $errmsg_arr[] = 'For missing';

        $errflag = true;

    }





    function findexts ($fname) { 

        $fname = strtolower($fname) ; 

        $extensions = split("[/\\.]", $fname) ; 

        $n = count($extensions)-1; 

        $extensions = $extensions[$n]; 

    }



    $target_path="../notice/";





    if($errflag) {

        $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;

        session_write_close();

        header("location: ../err.php");

        exit();

    }

if($_FILES['file']['error']==0){



    if(($_FILES['file']['size']<1000000)&&($_FILES['file']['type']=="application/msword")||($_FILES['file']['type']=="application/pdf")){



        $ext=findtext($_FILES['file']['name']);

        $random=rand(0,5);

        $random2=$random.".";

        $target=$target.$random2.$ext;

        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$target)){



            $qry="INSERT INTO PALMSIS.Notice(NoticeID,Name,Date,Timestamp,Type,Descr,By,For) VALUES('$random','$name',NOW(),NOW(),'$source','$Desc','$By','$For')";

            $result=@mysql_query($qry);

            if($result){

                header("location:./noticeupld.php");

                exit();

                }

                else{



                    die("query Failed");



                    }



            }

            else{



                header("location:./success.php");

                }

        }

        else{



            header("location:./noproper.php");



            }



    }

    else{



        header("location:./error.php");



        }?>
```

Comment: Unless you have configured error reporting settings somewhere else (php.ini for instance) you don't seem to have error reporting enabled. But this, of course, is essential to doing some decent programming. Having error reporting set to having errors displayed on screen (on your development server) with the maximum error level `(E_ALL | E_STRICT )` will give you all kinds of clues about what might be wrong.

Comment: [Same script as posted 4 hours ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443707/file-uploader-script-not-working-properly) - two answers, no feedback.

Comment: This calls for basic debugging.

Answer (score 1):

I would start with just uploading a file and see if that works... then add in your other pieces and see where the trouble begins.  This code assumes you have a form that has a text field named "file_name" where you designate what you'd like the file to be called when it's moved to the server, as well as a file field that is your file. Don't forget that your form has to be multipart.  That's something people frequently forget and is the cause of much trouble.

```
$fileName = $_REQUEST[ 'file_name' ];
$folder = "./";


if ( move_uploaded_file( $_FILES[ 'file' ][ 'tmp_name' ], $folder . $fileName ) ) {
        echo "SUCCESS:" . $folder.$fileName . " has been saved";

} 
else{
     echo "FAIL:";

}
```

Answer (score 1):

All I can think of off hand is that the files on this must be under 1mb which is easy for .pdf's with graphics to surpass...  I'd start with some basic troubleshooting techniques.

for instance:

```
if($_FILES['file']['error']==0){
    $flag = $flag+1;
    echo 'No errors reported on file upload<br>';
    }
if($_FILES['file']['size']<1000000){
    $flag = $flag+1;
    echo 'Size is confirmed under 1mb<br>';
    }
if(($_FILES['file']['type']=="application/msword")||($_FILES['file']['type']=="application/pdf")){
    $flag = $flag+1;
    echo 'Correct Filetype confirmed<br>';
    }
```

This way you know which ones are passing the checks.

Good luck mate!

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have to, but it would be good practice to initialize `$errflag` to false and `$errmsg_arr` to an empty array.